# array_merge is returning empty array when combining 2d arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to use array_merge to merge two 2d arrays, but the result is always empty. There is no need to show you the whole php class, but I will paste the relevent code here. The problem is that when I use array_merge I get an empty array. I am calling my function called charts which in turn gets 2 arrays by calling 2 functions, then I wish to merge these arrays. The array functions do return a valid array, but when I merge them, I get nothing.

```
public function charts(){
    $sales=$this->salesChart();
    $expenses=$this->$this->expensesChart();

    $result = array_merge($sales,$expenses);
    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}

private function salesChart(){      
    $salesArray = array(
        array('2016-05', 14690),array('2016-06', 2785),array('2016-07', 14690),array('2016-08',23345),array('2016-09', 10345),array('2016-10',12456)
    );
    return $salesArray;
}

private function expensesChart(){
    $expensesArray = array(
        array('2016-05', 14690),array('2016-06', 2785),array('2016-07', 14690),array('2016-08',23345),array('2016-09', 10345),array('2016-10',12456)
    );
    return $expensesArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
$expenses=$this->$this->expensesChart();
```

for

```
$expenses=$this->expensesChart();
```

because I tested the array_merge and it works.
It is what it seems for the code you have provided.

Comment: Wow i can't believe I missed that. I didn't intentionally put $this->$this in as that would be stupid. Now I am going bash myself with a wet kipper.